# When the gradient points in some particular direction, does it always point towards level curves of higher value?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is $k_6>k_5>\cdots>k_1$ (see image)?

[Levels curves of a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsfT2.gif)

[image]

Comment: Yes. $\nabla f$ points in the direction of greatest increase of $f$.

Comment: One-dimensional counterexample: if $f=x^2$, $\nabla f=0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: more accurately each > should be replaced by $\geq$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @J.G. So technically the question should be, "When the gradient points in some particular direction, does it always point towards ... ?" The example O.P. posted has that condition.

Comment: @DavidK Yes indeed. I'm changing the title of the question then.